# convert list from data series into a suitable data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of data series that looks something like this:

`list = np.array([[0.32689251, 0.32677079, 0.32649432, 0.32594585, 0.32532732, 0.32509514, 0.32503138, 0.32492934, 0.324797, 0.32458332], [0.32689251, 0.32677079, 0.32649432, 0.32594585, 0.32532732, 0.32509514, 0.32503138, 0.32492934, 0.324797, 0.32458332], [0.32689251, 0.32677079, 0.32649432, 0.32594585, 0.32532732, 0.32509514, 0.32503138, 0.32492934, 0.324797, 0.32458332]])`

I need to convert it to a pandas DataFrame that has the dimension 3x3. so for each data series one row and one column

by the following code, you only get a DataFrame of the format (3, 10):

`df = pd.DataFrame(list)`

Comment: I don't understand your question. If your sublists have 10 elements each, that is what is going to be there in the output. How can you expect it to have 3X3 structure? 7 observations are not going to disappear without a reason. Is there a logic by which you want to select certain values from each list?
If you want 3 columns, reduce the number of values. Or, create a dataframe, drop the columns you dont need.

Answer (score 1):

try this. I would not recommend to use reserved word like "list" for variable names.
This might create just noice if not errors.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list).transpose()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the name of the variable is of course different in my code and serves here only as a placeholder. Unfortunately the .transpose() function did not work properly. I get a DataFrame of dimension (10, 3) and in each cell is only one value of one of the three data series of my list. But I need to make the cells contain the whole data series.

Comment: would you please ammend you original question and write the desired output as an table. Do it with a smaller amount of values @alpa